# Combine REST and SOAP service in same class?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I have a running `SOAP` service, and would like to also publish the same method as `REST`. Is it possible to use `REST` in the same class?

```
@Component
@WebService
public class MyService extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {
    @WebMethod
    //@GET
    public String ping(@WebParam("input") String test) {
        return test;
    }
}

<jaxws:endpoint implementor="de.test.MyService" address="/MyService" />
<!-- <jaxrs:server serviceClass="de.test.MyService" address="/HRSService" /> -->
```

If I comment the `@GET` and the `jaxrs` out, the following error is thrown:

```
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: There is an endpoint already running on /MyService.
```

So, can't I run both in the same service.

Comment: That's bad design. Create a business service class that does the work and two wrappers - one for JAX-WS and one for JAX-RS

Comment: I certainly agree that a business service class, to retrieve the model/data, is good practise, however, depending on how your data is requested/input, you might 'get away' with a combined JSON/SOAP-returning functions strategy (please refer to my answer, below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did just this a few years back so that a 3rd party mobile application developer could integrate my company's product data on their own terms (either using SOAP or REST/JSON, they  chose REST/JSON for their iPhone app). I created a sanitised version, for reference at:

[m2-soap-rest](https://github.com/sixman9/m2-soap-rest) ([Maven](http://maven.apache.org)-built JAX-WS/JAX-RS example project)

I use singular methods to output both formats, from the same model(s). If you refer to the interface/class implementation combo of:

[SoapRestServiceIntf.java](https://github.com/sixman9/m2-soap-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/soap/rest/service/SoapRestServiceIntf.java)
[SoapRestServiceImpl.java](https://github.com/sixman9/m2-soap-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/soap/rest/service/impl/SoapRestServiceImpl.java)

then, hopefully, you'll get an idea of what I did in order to return either SOAP/XML (JAX-WS) or REST/JSON (JAX-RS) from the same method/object representations.

Please refer to annotations such as '**@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }**)', which depends on the calling client's requested ['Accept' header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (this dictates the client's expected response format).

Nostalgically, passing back over my code has led me to notice some omissions (it was a 1st attempt), however, coincidently, I very recently had to revisit REST/JSON using JAX-RS/CXF, so I have a more actual JAX-RS project, with input type specification annotations, field validation and RESTful testing (using [REST-assured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured)), which can be found at:

[FeedbackCXF](https://github.com/sixman9/FeedbackCXF) ([Gradle](http://www.gradle.org)-built JAX-RS example project)

***This newer project does not output both data types***, I mention it as you might find it useful for further reference.

I personally cannot vouch for whether this is best practice or not, it simply worked for me at the time.

I hope you find this useful.

BTW If you're wondering about the switch away from [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org) is No-XML (less verbose easier to read) and is basically standard [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) code (i.e. Java-like, able to do a simple for-loop/normal programming etc., during the build process).

Comment: That's a great solution with interface and implementation for both rest and soap!